C program to visualize va_args, confusing behavior
I ran across va_args while learning some C and I wrote the following to try and better understand how it works:
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                            
#include <stdarg.h>
 
void print_numbers(int num, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, num);
    char firstchar = va_arg(args, int);
    printf("%c", firstchar);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        int val = va_arg(args, int );
        printf("%d", val);
    }
    va_end(args);
    printf("\n");
}
 
int main() {
    print_numbers(4,'s',12,13,14);
    return 0;
}

My goal here is to first print out the char in the args ('s') and then the rest of the numbers. However, I'm observing some interesting behavior when I run the program, the output after:
gcc vargs.c -o vargs

is random after s121314:
s121314-602312640
s121314-102502336
s1213142121265216

and I'm not really sure what's going on here

You have an off-by-one error. Your loop should be counting i=1..num

apologies! s should be there, i miswrote the s to c!

From cppreference:

T va_arg( va_list ap, T ); 

If va_arg is called when there are no more arguments in ap, the behavior is undefined.


You get the first argument after the num parameter with
char firstchar = va_arg(args, int);

and then you get the others:
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    int val = va_arg(args, int );
    printf("%d", val);
}

You go from i = 0 to i < num, which means that you are getting num arguments plus the one you got for firstchar. In total you try to obtain num + 1 arguments which is UB. This means that everything can happen. It can print garbage or crash or whatever else.
To fix it just start the loop at i = 1.

so the first va_arg takes one off the list, and then the loop iterates for one longer than expected (because there's one less) and ends up printing whatever is in the heap?

@Mathew "so the first va_arg takes one off the list, and then the loop iterates for one longer than expected", yes. "whatever is in the heap" well the thing about UB (undefined behavior) is that it is undefined. You don't know what happens. This could be the case but there just isn't a way to safely tell what is going on since it is undefined.
